# C++ Trouble accessing an object from a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm new to C++, so this is probably an easy question. I have a vector of vectors declared in the class Predictor:

```
class Predictor{
    std::vector<std::vector<BitCounter>> data;
public:
    Predictor();
    void addBit(int x);
};
```

BitCounter is declared as:

```
class BitCounter {
    short int count0 = 0;
    short int count1 = 0;
public:
    BitCounter();
    short int getCount0();
    short int getCount1();
    void addBit(int x);
};
```

In Predictor::addBit, I have the lines:

```
BitCounter bit_counter = data[i][j];
printf("%p %p\n", &bit_counter, &data[i][j]);
```

This gives me two distinct addresses, where I was expecting to get identical addresses. What boneheaded error am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes a `BitCounter` copy:

```
BitCounter bit_counter = data[i][j];
```

Here, `bit_counter` is a copy of whatever is in `data[i][j]`, and therefore has a different address.

If you want to reference the element in your nested vector, you can use a reference instead:

```
const BitCounter& bit_counter = data[i][j];
```

Here, `bit_counter` is an alias for whatever is in `data[i][j]` and therefore the address-of operator will yield the same address for both:

```
const BitCounter& bit_counter = data[i][j];
std::cout << &bit_counter << "\n";
std::cout << &data[i][j] << "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

These are two distinct objects. `&bit_counter` is the address of the local variable, where `&data[i][j]` is the address of the object inside `Vector`.

`BitCounter bit_counter = data[i][j];` means "construct a new `BitCounter` object using the value of `data[i][j]`". The main difference between this and `new BitCounter(data[i][j])` (which is somewhat more similar to things happen in Java/C#) is that in our case the lifetime of the object is limited by the scope of the variable - namely, the current block.

So, if you want to get similar (but not identical) behavior to Java, you should use a pointer type, which makes the `printf` statement obvoius:

```
BitCounter* bit_counter = &data[i][j];
printf("%p %p\n", bit_counter, &data[i][j]);
```

you can use references, as suggested here:

```
const BitCounter& bit_counter = data[i][j];
printf("%p %p\n", &bit_counter, &data[i][j]);
```

but note that a reference cannot be changed, unlike the case with references in Java/C#, so an assignment to bit_counter (if it was not constant) will change the referenced object itself.

Comment: Thanks! I'm coming from objective-C, where objects are always passed by reference, and I couldn't see the obvious. But, I never encountered & on the left-hand side of an assignment operator, so your answer got me to look into this further.